# Wordpress administration is gone after creating base theme

Tags: theme-development

I have following files for a base theme:

- wp-content/themes/base/style.css (empty)
- wp-content/themes/base/index.php

```
// index.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

echo wp_nav_menu();
```

After switching the theme to the base theme, `http://localhost:8085` shows a base page with naviagtion items, so far so good.
Now I want to add more navigation items in the admin area. But when I go to `http://localhost:8085/wp-admin/`, the same content is shown as in `http://localhost:8085`, wihtout administration toolbars.
How can I add pages or even change the theme back?

I can't believe a custom theme also affects the administration theme.

Comment: Do you mean you can’t access wp-admin at all? Or just that after logging in you don’t see the admin bar on the front end? If it’s the latter then you need to add wp_head() and wp_footer() to your theme. This should all be covered in the theme handbook.

Comment: When I access `/wp-admin`, I see the same content as in `/`. I can't log in, since I see only the menu items outputted from `wp_nav_menu()`. I just want to access the Wordpress administration to add pages or change the activated theme.